How to get rid of HTTP Proxy authentication on Android Studio?
I am using Android Studio Koala | 2024.1.1
My proxy server doesn't have a password.
It always asks me for my username and password.
I've been suffering from this problem for a long time.
I tried a fresh install of Android Studio and it doesn't seem to work!
I've searched the web for information but came up empty handed and I don't understand why this is.

I've tried numerous times to change this option, but it automatically resets itself to checked!
If possible, I would like someone with experience to share how to solve this problem.

Same issues here for a couple of years. Don't now why this option is always selected by itself, no matter how many times you have disabled it. What a shame that this tiny issue get haunting there for years!

Found a workaround for this: in the modal, inputs some random username and password, turn on the Remember option, and hope your proxy server will ignore your inputs.

I've noticed this; proxy servers are very clever!
